# Setting a string property to \n in the settings designer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, settings, application-settings

In the visual studio settings designer, how can a setting with string type be set to the newline character? Entering `\n` results in the string being set to literally `\n` - the escape sequence doesn't seem to have meaning in the setting seditor. So how do I set a setting's value to a non-printable character?

The settings designer edits the App.config (xml) file and the Settings.settings file. I thought about editing the App.config file directly, but entering `\n` there again sets the string to literally `\n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the down arrow in the Default value edit box.  To get this (note the gray text):

[image]

Comment: That's a partial solution but I'm really interested in the general case of any 'escaped character'. How would I enter a carriage retern ('\r') for example?

Comment: Hmm, no, that covers any kind of setting value.  There is no 'general case', a UITypeEditor that accept Enter keystrokes is required but not always provided in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

There will be a designer file that goes with your form — either `formname.designer.cs` or `formname.designer.vb`, depending on which language you use.  You'll have to edit this file to include your newline.

This is one of the few cases where I ever recommend touching this file.  Most of the time it should be left alone, and your alteration placed in your form's constructor, InitializeComponent() method, or an event line OnLoad or OnActivate.

Comment: There's no form involved. I'm talking about the settings designer, which edits the App.config file and the Settings.settings file.

Comment: @Tim - ah. In that case, you edit the settings file directly.